# pythonic way to flatten nested lists?

Tags: python, list, flatten

I have a list-tuple-list tree and I'd like to flatten it for a query, so that I can print all the items of the the first lists of each tuple.

I can do it via a for loop:

```
bigNest = [([item1,item2],[]),([item3],[item4])]
mergedlist = []
for listItem in bigNest:
   mergedlist += listItem[0]
print mergedList
```

Is there a simpler/quicker way which will also work with larger tuples?

Comment: Have you done a search for "flatten"? This has been answered 100 times.

Comment: There are a lot of different ways to do, as discussed in the previous answers (which is why I'm voting to close).  There's terse but slow (`sum(nested_list, [])`) or the various itertools-based solutions (e.g. `itertools.chain`) which will scale up considerably better.

Comment: I did actually search but I obviously didn't hit the right keywords because none of the topics above came up

Comment: Also, sorry but none of the "possible duplicates" above answer my question. I know how to flatten if I want to. I want the pythonic way to do it. The ones listed are all bigger than mine!

Comment: `print list(chain.from_iterable(item for item in chain.from_iterable(bigNest) if item))`

Comment: None of them explicitly answer the exact same question (you only want to flatten the first item, instead of flattening recursively). However, you can use the exact same tricks. E.g. `merged = sum([item[0] for item in nested], [])`

Comment: I'm surprised you didn't hit the right keyword, as you used "flatten" both in the title and question and it's very relevant and specific. The reason your answer is shorter is because it's a specific subset of the general problem, where you're only merging a particular nesting level.

Comment: You are probably right but that's why I asked! Unfortunately I'm not that good with python to be able to figure if code made for something different will work with what I need to do.

Comment: @JoeKington unfortunately, that didn't work. It ended up duplicating the content.

Comment: You might have succeeded in asking the question if you pointed out some of the other questions/answers and why they were not sufficient.

Comment: I honestly just wanted a quick question. I didn't want to write a whole essay. I saw someone asking how to simply combine lists and they got an answer so I thought me putting an existing solution and asking for a more refined one would be enough.

Forget it...

Comment: "which will also work with larger tuples?" It's not clear what the intended concern was. `listItem[0]` will work no matter how many elements are in `listItem`, *as long as there is at least one*.

Answer (score 1):

edit: sorry the last post was wrong, you could do a list comprehension:

```
mergedlist = []
foovar = [mergedlist.extend(i[0]) for i in bigNest]
```

Comment: Can I simply throw that into a print?

I.e. can I `print [mergedlist.extend(i) for i in bigNest]`?

Comment: Also, won't that extend my list by just adding the tuples? I need to go deeper.

Comment: oh yes, sorry, I meant `.extend(i[0])`

Comment: Please do not abuse list comprehensions for the side effects.